# checkbox not displaying checked after putting checked attribute

Tags: html, checkbox, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have an $lc public array variable in my livewire which contains a boolean.
in my view, I have this.

```
<input @if($lc[$uaf->id]) checked @endif  wire:model.prevent.defer="lc.{{ $uaf->id }}" id="lc.{{ $uaf->id }}" type="checkbox" />
```

the value of `$lc[$uaf->id]` is 1 which in boolean represents true. So, it should display a checked box.

but the display is this.
[image: 0]
it's not checked.

I have already done this

```
$lc[$uaf->id] = $uaf->classification->for_locational_clearance;
```

but it's no luck.

Comment: You're not using Livewire correctly. Have a read over in the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding) to get some understanding of data binding

Comment: I fixed it just today... I removed this @if($lc[$uaf->id]) checked @endif          and its just 
<input wire:model.prevent.defer="lc.{{ $uaf->id }}" type="checkbox" />.          And it is now working correctly and properly.

Comment: Tomorrow i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my livewire

```
    foreach($this->applicant->uafs as $uaf ){
        $this->lc[$uaf->id] = $uaf->classification ? $uaf->classification->for_locational_clearance : false;
    }
```

and in my blade file

```
<input wire:model.prevent.defer="lc.{{ $uaf->id }}" id="lc.{{ $uaf->id }}" type="checkbox" />
```